# How to convert the result of intersection of two arrays into integer Array  from a SQL query to an Integer array in postgresql

Tags: arrays, postgresql, rails-postgresql

Query 1:

```
SELECT ARRAY(select id from contacts where id = 0)::INT[],
       ARRAY[]::INT[],
       ARRAY(SELECT id FROM contacts WHERE id = 0)::INT[] = ARRAY[]::int[]
```

Produces this result:

```
int4    array   ?column?                                                                    
{}      {}      TRUE
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT (ARRAY(SELECT id FROM contacts WHERE id = 0)::INT[]
      & ARRAY(select id from contacts where id = 0)::INT[]),
        ARRAY[]::INT[],
       (ARRAY(SELECT id FROM contacts WHERE id = 0)::INT[]
      & ARRAY(SELECT id FROM contacts WHERE id = 0)::INT[]) = ARRAY[]::int[]
```

Produces a different result:

```
?column?    array   ?column?                                                            
{}              {}      FALSE
```

Why the difference?

Is there any other way to compare an empty integer array with the result of an intersection of two arrays like in the second query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard PostgreSQL does not support the ARRAY intersection operator. You must have installed the [additional module **intarray**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/intarray.html).

Your question boils down to this:
The intersection of two empty integer arrays yields an empty integer array. Why does this query yield `false`?

```
SELECT ('{}'::int[] & '{}'::int[]) = '{}'::int[]
```

Or in other syntax, meaning the same:

```
SELECT (ARRAY[]::int[] & ARRAY[]::int[]) = ARRAY[]::int[]
```

While this yields `true`:

```
SELECT '{}'::int[] = '{}'::int[]
```

And yes, that is a **very good question**.

---

For what it's worth, I can **explain the difference**:

```
SELECT array_dims('{}'::int[])
<NULL>

SELECT array_dims('{}'::int[] & '{}'::int[])
[1:0]
```

In other words, the first one is just an empty array, while the second one is a one-dimensional array with an empty element.

This can be very confusing. For instance see this thread about [how to treat string_to_array() with empty output](http://grokbase.com/t/postgresql.org/pgsql-hackers/2010/08/string-to-array-with-an-empty-input-string/103cg4uqpwyhexuqdx3pjixmhjaq).
I am not sure the `&` operator does the right thing here.